# Representing a 3-dimensional Grid of Spheres

Tags: java, data-structures

Overall goal: Given a list of points in 3-dimensional space, I need to generate a sphere around that point given the point's radius and then pro grammatically check if there is space between two or more spheres given a certain point.

Problem: I'm having trouble thinking of a data structure to represent a grid of points (that represent the center of the sphere) and the surrounding sphere, these may not always be hole numbers.

Example Data: 
Point A: (-3, .25, 4) Radius: 1.35 
Point B: (5, 6.35, 1) Radius: 2 
Point C: (1, 0, -1) Radius: .5

My original idea was to have a 3-dimensional array of integers that was of size the absolute value of the maximum and minimum values of the axes added together divided by the smallest accuracy you wanted. You would then use a conversion factor to convert from the array location (whole integers) to the decimal location of a point you were looking for. I would then fill in the array with some data to represent that a sphere exists around the sphere center.

What I'm looking for is the data structure I should use to represent this 3d grid of non-whole numbers. I feel like my technique isn't correct.

This is in Java.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just represent them with the 3 coordinates x,y,z (3d-point) and the radius, just as you listed them and use (3dimensional) distance to evaluate if points are inside a sphere or not?
Or am I missing the use case here? This sounds like it: "check if there is space between two or more spheres given a certain point"

Answer (score 0):

I actually did something very similar earlier this week.
What I did is decide the minimum distance two points are allowed to have (here for you found by adding the radii of your two spheres if I understood you correctly). Using this I created a random field of spheres using a starting sphere at (0, 0, 0) and then incrementally add extra spheres a random distance away from that.
Since in my case (not sure if you need this as well) I also had a maximum distance I just shifted the coordinates of one of the already accepted spheres and check whether the distances matched.

So, to summarize:

1. Have a starting point
2. Randomly place a point (within a specific range) to one of your existing points
3. Check if it meets your spacing restrictions
4. Repeat 2-3 until you have enough spheres.

Hope that's any help to anybody.